# How to select more columns than insert column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following query:

```
INSERT INTO TableA (Col1, Col2, Col3)
OUTPUT @SomeData, INSERTED.ID, ID INTO TableB(SomeColumn, TableAID, ID)
SELECT Col1, Col2, Col3, ID
FROM TableC;
```

When I run it, I get this error:

> The select list for the INSERT statement contains more items than the insert list. The number of SELECT values must match the number of INSERT columns.

That error makes sense, but I don't know how to fix it. I want to select 4 columns from `TableC`, but I want to only insert three of them (Col1, Col2, Col3) into `TableA`. I am selecting the column `ID` because I want to insert it into the `ID` column of `TableB`. Is there any way to do that?

```
CREATE TABLE TableA
(
    ID bigint identity
        constraint PK_TableA_ID
            primary key
    Col1 int,
    Col2 int,
    Col3 int
)

CREATE TABLE TableB
(
    ID          [int]                NOT NULL,
    SomeColumn  [int]                NOT NULL,
    TableAID    [bigint]             NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE TableC
(
    ID          [int] IDENTITY (1,1) NOT NULL,
    Col1        [int],
    Col2        [int],
    Col3        [int],

);
```

Comment: What is the structure of TableA and TableB?

Comment: _"I want to select 4 columns from TableC, but I want to only insert three of them"_ You're `INSERT`ing 4 columns instead of `SELECT`ing them. If you want to `SELECT` those columns, then you should write them in `OUTPUT` clause not in the `SELECT` statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try merge and write something like this:

```
MERGE TableA AS target
USING TableC AS source 
ON 1 = 0
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY target
THEN INSERT (Col1, Col2, Col3) VALUES (source.Col1, source.Col2, source.Col3)
OUTPUT @SomeData, INSERTED.ID, source.ID INTO TableB (SomeColumn,TableAID, ID);
```